# How to change the font size and font color after form submission

Tags: php, html, css, forms, fonts

Hi iam trying to do simple form for my website.

iam only able to change the size of the form [Like This](http://oi60.tinypic.com/f20zdw.jpg) but not able to change font size and color after submission you can view [Here](http://oi58.tinypic.com/fnvfo1.jpg)

Iam also attaching the code please view and give me good suggestion.

The below is the html code

```
<html>
<body align="center" bgcolor="#DCDCDC">
<frameset rows="25%,*">
<frame src="" name="f4">
<img src="GRIET1.png" height="25%" width="100%"></img>
</frameset>

<form action="updates.php" method="post">

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<font size="4"</font>UserID:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="userid" size="25"><br>
<br>
UserName: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="username" size="25"><br>
<br>
Password: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="password" size="25"><br>
<br>
Department: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="department" size="25"><br>
<br>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The below is the php code

```
Welcome 

Userid is: <?php echo $_POST["userid"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["username"]; ?><br>
password is: <?php echo $_POST["password"]; ?><br>
Department is:<?php echo $_POST["department"]; ?><br>
```

I also used html and body open and closing tags in php to reduce the code size iam not showing in php my main problem is how to change the font size and color after submitting the form thats it.

Answer (score 1):

i congrats you to encorauge to enter this world.
About your problem is really simple. PHP dont create styles, but css can.

So you can make something like this:

```
Welcome 

Userid is: <div style="font-size:16px; color:red"> <?php echo $_POST["userid"]; ?></div><br>
Your email address is: <div style="font-size:14pt; color: #FF6A6A"> <?php echo $_POST["username"]; ?><div><br>
```

And so on, i encorauge you to see some videos about HTML5 and CSS3 Tutorials, then it would be a good idea to see some PHP videos and so on.
Take care

Sorry for bad english though.

Comment: Possibly look at giving the `div` tags a class so they can be altered from a stylesheet